# Fql query Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook-fql

I am facing ERROR 400 BAD REQUEST on this query::

```
string str=ds.Table[0].Rows[0].ItemArray.toString();


fbfr =string.Format( "/fql?q=SELECT+uid+,+ name+,+ pic_square+,+affiliations+,+birthday_date+,+sex+,+relationship_status+,+hometown_location+,+current_location+,+education_history+,+work_history+,+contact_email+ FROM+ user+ WHERE+(sex='male')+AND+uid+ IN +(SELECT+ uid2+ FROM +friend+ WHERE+ uid1={0})" ,str);
    string ser = api.Get(fbfr, true);
```

Its able to access the `uid` from `Dataset ds`, but fails to run the query.
Please give your inputs.

Comment: For one, you've got a lot of bare spaces in there. `+ IN +` should probably be just `+IN+` and so on - this makes the query string be mis-encoded and probably rejected as bad.

Comment: Removed the spaces, but still no success Marc

Comment: What is `uid1={0}`?  try using `uid1=me()` for the current user

Comment: I am fetching data for other uids in this query which are in dataset. I checkd me() is working..but I don't have to use that

Answer (score 1):

> I am fetching data for other uids in this query which are in dataset. I checkd me() is working..but I don't have to use that

You cannot get "friends of friends".  It's strictly not allowed by the API.  You can only get friends of the current user. Even if the 400 error is being caused by something else, you will only be able to get friends of the current user.

Comment: Yes I am getting data of friends of the person who signed into my site.

Comment: No, you cannot get friends of a user's friend.   `(SELECT+ uid2+ FROM +friend+ WHERE+ uid1={0})` cannot work where the {0} parameter is a friend's ID.  It has to be the ID of the app user.  The shorthand for this is `(SELECT+ uid2+ FROM +friend+ WHERE+ uid1=me())`.

Comment: But how can i get information of friends of the user signed in??its important for a functionality in my site

Comment: Graph API request for `/${USER_ID}/friends` works if `${USER_ID}` has authorised the app.  (If not you get the message `(#604) Can't lookup all friends of 123. Can only lookup for the logged in user or the logged in user's friends that are users of your app.`)